# Displaying graph using python online compiler with matlab library

Tags: python, matlab

I've written a program with python to display a graph with matlab library which displays it in a new window with python3. I would like to use an online compiler (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php) so that I would be able to share the program, but because this requires matlab to open a window, the online compiler fails. How am I able to solve this?

Comment: You probably mean `matplotlib`, not `matlab`, right?

Comment: Yes sorry. I meant matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just send the entire `.py` file to someone else so they can run it on their computer? As far as I know, there is no option for running Python code online without requiring a download / installation that is free where you can also install libraries (like `matplotlib`).

Comment: No because I would also like to share it with people online in a web interface

Comment: You will need to run your own Python server to do this, then. If you want to do it 100% statically without running a server, you can use a Javascript library to draw a plot instead.